# How do I remove light from Material Preview Shading in the 3D viewport?

Tags: light

How do I remove light from my viewport so it's completely black?

I have deleted the light and adjusted world settings. However, there still seems to be some light.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default **Material Preview Shading** uses a different environment and lighting than the **Rendered Shading** so it ignores the world settings.

In the **Options** tab, you can choose to use scene world and lighting .

[image]

Comment: I tried that in the rendered view but it doesn't become completely black

Comment: That setting is for Material Preview shading. The rendered view will use the settings for the "world", as well as the lighting of the scene.

Comment: I just realised I baked my indirect lighting and forgot to delete it. Thank you for your help